# Como sumar elementos de una matriz en python

Tags: python

Tengo que realizar un programa de gestión de envíos, el programa me pide que guarde la llegada de camiones, para ello me pide que guarde un camión que va numerado del 1 al 3 segun el tipo de camion 1=tanquero 2=caja 3= plataforma y que ponga la cantidad de camiones que han llegado, es decir han llegado 5 camiones tanqueros. El problema que tengo es que pide que sume los camiones que van llegando del mismo tipo, si primero pongo que llegan 5 tanqueros y luego 5 mas que ponga que hay 10 tanqueros. Los datos los guardo en una matriz y mi problema es como puedo recorrer la matriz para que me sume los diferentes camiones según van llegando.

Pregunta del ejercicio: 
Se pedirá al usuario el tipo de camión que ha llegada (1 = Plataforma, 2 = Tanquero o 3
= Caja) y cuantos camiones (entero entre 1 y 10).
Sumará los nuevos camiones a los que ya estaban disponibles.
Pregunta si queremos introducir otra llegada de camiones o salir al menú principal.

Aquí mi código.

```
def llegadaCamion():
   while True:
     nuevos_Camiones=[]
     input("Has pulsado la opción de Llegada de camion  ...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
     #input donde capturamos los datos que vamos a pedir al camion
     tipoCamion=(input("Introduce el tipo de camion: 1=Plataforma, 2=Tanquero, 3=Caja :"))
     #ahora introducimos el campo que tenemos en el array utilizando append
     nuevos_Camiones.append(tipoCamion)
     cantidadCamiones=int(input("Introduce el numero de camiones que han llegado, maximo 10 camiones: "))
        #Vamos a crear una condición para que nos avise si introducimos mas de 10 camiones 
     if cantidadCamiones <=10:
        nuevos_Camiones.append(cantidadCamiones)
        lista_llegada_camiones.append(nuevos_Camiones)
        print(lista_llegada_camiones[:])
     else:
        print("Estas introduciendo mas de 10 camiones!!!!!!")
        cantidadCamiones=int(input("Introduce el numero de camiones que han llegado, maximo 10 camiones: "))
        nuevos_Camiones.append(cantidadCamiones)
        lista_llegada_camiones.append(nuevos_Camiones)

     opcion_terminar=(input("Si quieres introducir un nuevo camion pulsa 1, en caso de volver al menu principal pulsa 2: "))
     if opcion_terminar =="1":
        llegadaCamion()
     elif opcion_terminar =="2":
            break
```

Comment: Para "sumar los elementos de una lista en Python": `suma = sum(lista)`

Comment: Bienvenido David, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.  También es muy importante ver [ask] para ver como mejorar tus preguntas, que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Puntualmente, tu pregunta pareciera ser más bien "Como sumar una lista por grupos", la explicación pero sobre todo el código no parece aportar mucho en ese sentido. Te sugiero que veas el módulo `collections` y el objeto `Counter` ver: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter. Sumar una lista por grupos, es bastante sencillo usándolo: `from collections import Counter;print(Counter([2,2,2,1,3,3,1]))`

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te sirva, tu condicion de limite de 10 camiones me parece un poco frágil, esa parte te la dejo como reflexión.

Vale la pena recordar que defaultdict crea diccionarios con valores iniciales ya definidos, es basicamente una forma segura de crear diccionarios quando no sabemos cuales van a ser todas las llaves.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def llegadaCamion():
   nc = defaultdict(int)
   while True:
     # Capturamos el tipo de camion
     tipoCamion=(input("Introduce el tipo de camion: 1=Plataforma, 2=Tanquero, 3=Caja :"))
     cantidadCamiones=int(input("Introduce el numero de camiones que han llegado, maximo 10 camiones: "))

     # Limitamos el número de camiones a 10   
     if cantidadCamiones <=10:
        nc[tipoCamion] += cantidadCamiones
     else:
        print("Estas introduciendo mas de 10 camiones!!!!!!")
        cantidadCamiones=int(input("Introduce el numero de camiones que han llegado, maximo 10 camiones: "))
        nc[tipoCamion] += cantidadCamiones

     opcion_terminar=(input("Si quieres introducir un nuevo camion pulsa 1, en caso de volver al menu principal pulsa 2: "))
     if opcion_terminar =="2":
            return dict(nc)

print(llegadaCamion())
```